# How to get Mission Control to show what is on a second monitor?

Tags: osx-lion, mission-control

I am using Mission Control on OS X 10.7.  I have a second monitor, but when I launch Mission Control, it doesn't show me what is on the second monitor.  Is there anything I can do to get it to come up?

Comment: Doesn't this break the NDA? Voting to close based on that.

Answer (score 2):

Watch your NDA.

That aside, look at your second monitor.